# Writing in a log with StreamWriter and Trace Listeners is very slow

Tags: c#, performance, streamwriter

I'm facing a problem here, i'm in internship right now, and I have to modify a given program.
I had some lag issue, and i finally found the problem : the log writer ...

The more the program was running, the more it was slow, and actually. I found out it was because of the streamwriter for the logfile, here is the code :

```
using (StreamWriter swLog = new StreamWriter(GenerateDaylog(_logPath), true))
{    
    String sLog = "";
    sLog += DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString();
    sLog += " ";
    sLog += DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString();
    sLog += "\t";
    sLog += new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name;
    sLog += "\t";
    sLog += new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;
    sLog += "\t";
    sLog += msg;
    Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(swLog));
    Trace.WriteLine(sLog);          
}
```

The log files are about 100 - 500 ko right now, every day a new logfile is created with the date in the name of it.

I guess there is a problem with the streamwriter, but I can't figure out what it is.

Comment: for logging there are some framework that work async and fast such as EnterpriseLibrary, if you are writing business application I suggest you to take a look at them.

Comment: It is much better to use external frameworks for logging as suggested by @RezaRahmati. Try also Log4Net.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is probably the issue:

```
Trace.Listeners.Add(new TextWriterTraceListener(swLog));
```

Every time you add a log entry, you're adding an extra trace listener... so the first time, you'll get one log entry. The second time, you'll get two (new) log entries, etc. You should be able to see this in your log (although as you're adding a listener and then disposing of the writer, it's not really clear what will happen).

It's not clear why you're using `Trace.WriteLine` at all given that you know exactly what you're trying to write to - why not just use `swLog.WriteLine(...)`?

Also, I'd encourage you to use `string.Format` instead of all that repeated string concatenation... and ideally use a dedicated logging framework (e.g. [NLog](http://nlog-project.org/) or [log4Net](http://logging.apache.org/log4net/)) instead.

Comment: Nothing more to add here.

Comment: Or a `StringBuilder`.

Comment: Line 4 to 22 could be replaced with: `String sLog = String.Format("{0} {1}\t{2}\t{3}\t{4}", DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString(), DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString, new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().DeclaringType.Name, new StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name, msg);`

Comment: @rene: Yes, that's non-ideal... and using C#'s caller info attributes, it can be avoided entirely. But that's not going to be the biggest problem here :)

Comment: My internship supervior wrote this code, not me.
Funny fact : he told me last week " you better use string.format " haha :)
I'm really not familiar with those Trace & streamwriter but that was the problem :
1ms to ping in stead of 5 second after 10 minutes of running.
Well I have to say, stackoverflow keep impressing me, fast & clear what else do I need ?

Comment: @Pyr0technicien you're just lucky that Jon Skeet happened to answer your question. :)